# http-kit what is the difference between sending response through channel and just return a map

Tags: clojure, http-kit

As the title says. What is the difference between sending response through a channel and just return a map.

```
(defn handler-one
  [request]
  (response "hello world")

(defn handler-two
  [request]
  (with-channel request channel
    (send! channel (response "hello world"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handler-one` function uses synchronous approach. Request -> Response

`handle-two` is a way to achieve Request -> Response but **asynchronously**.

You can check [with-channel](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/master/src/org/httpkit/server.clj#L96) macro definition for more implementation details (and documentation).

If you want more details about asynchronous approach in general, then I recommend learning about one of: Futures, Reactive Programming, Netty, Node.js or Vert.x

Answer (score 1):

Following the theory of core.async channels, if you use channels you will have non-blocking communication meaning that your thread will not be blocked until the http response. If you use the blocking communication waiting for the map http-response your thread will be blocked